# How can i get my visited pages URL links?

Tags: javascript, html

How can i get my visited pages URL links with javascript fucntion?

Is it possible one page's javascript function runs then, save other tabs visited page log?

Comment: Hi jeongwonlee, welcome to SO! Kindly elaborate on your problem, and add whatever code you have tried so far - so people can help you better.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]